# QueryDSL order by subquery count

Tags: java, count, subquery, querydsl

I want to implement the following SQL query with QueryDSL:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    a
ORDER BY (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        b
    WHERE
        b.a_id = a.id
        AND b.c = 1) DESC
```

If I omit the criteria "b.c = 1", it's quite easy:

```java
selectFrom(a).orderBy(a.bs.size().desc());
```

But I can't find a way (simple or not) to include a criteria in the subquery.
I want my QueryDSL query to return a List<A> and not Tuple, if possible.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: why do you want subquery in order by clause?

Comment: @Shekhavat Do you know a better way to implement this logic ?